# .tsx instead of .js in app directory for a new NextJS projet

Tags: next.js

When I create a new NextJS app the 'app' directory contains 'tsx' files like 'layout.tsx' etc. but I want 'js' file like 'layout.js'.

For the part
Would you like to use TypeScript? ... No / Yes
Though I opted for No but I don't know what is the problem here.